# liquibase - create index for postgresql foreign keys

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing, foreign-keys, liquibase

We are using liquibase changesets to support usage of MySQL and PostgreSQL; Now I've stumbled over the fact that MySQL creates indexes for foreign keys automatically where postgres does not.

**Question:** How do I make sure that the DB schema has indexes for all foreign keys regardless of which DB actually is used?

**Update 28.02.2017**
Here is the link to a question in the liquibase forum: http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000001637005

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 'dbms' precondition here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html. You can put all postgesql-specific code there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out preconditions. However, that seems like a tortuous solution, since I'd have to manually create all the missing indices for postgres there. Plus, for every new Foreign Key which will be introduced, one would have to remember to also create such a postgres specific changeset.

Comment: Yet another disadvantage in the illusion of RDBMS portability.

Comment: @SebastianRiemer yes, I agree. Just saw that there is custom change tag: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html. So if you are familiar with Java you can try to build myForeignKey tag that will check database vendor and generate query to create index if required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to resolve this with a CustomChange-Command:

```
public class AddForeignKeyConstraintWithIndex extends
liquibase.change.core.AddForeignKeyConstraintChange implements
liquibase.change.custom.CustomSqlChange {

@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration", "FieldCanBeLocal"})
private ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor;

@Override
public void setUp() throws SetupException {
}

@Override
public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) {
    this.resourceAccessor = resourceAccessor;
}

@Override
public SqlStatement[] generateStatements(Database database) {
    SqlStatement[] result = super.generateStatements(database);
    // Für Postgres zusätzlich Index anlegen
    if (database instanceof PostgresDatabase) {
        AddColumnConfig columnConfig = new AddColumnConfig();
        columnConfig.setName(getBaseColumnNames());
        columnConfig.setComputed(Boolean.FALSE);

        SqlStatement createIndexStatement = new CreateIndexStatement(
                "ix_" + getConstraintName(),
                getBaseTableCatalogName(),
                getBaseTableSchemaName(),
                getBaseTableName(),
                Boolean.FALSE,
                null,
                columnConfig
        );
        List<SqlStatement> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(result));
        list.add(createIndexStatement);

        return list.toArray(new SqlStatement[list.size()]);

    }
    return result;
}
```

You then can call this CustomChange as this (with exactly the same params as for the AddForeignKeyConstraint-statement):

```
<customChange
class="eu.***.***.AddForeignKeyConstraintWithIndex"
        baseTableName="tbl_interest_reference"
        baseColumnNames="customer_id"
        constraintName="finterest_ref_customer_fk"
        referencedTableName="tbl_customer"
        referencedColumnNames="customer_id"
    />
```